# Creating explicitly specialized template class object yields "object has initializer but incomplete type" error

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Simple case. I don't quite understand why the parentheses are necessary for calling the default ctor of the explicitly instantiated template.
And, why calling the non-default ctor of the explicitly instantiated template gives me the "incomplete type" error?

Thank you very much!

```
// X.h
template <const int MODE>
class X{
public:
    X() = default;
    X(int& a) {++a;}
    // define X here
};
// declare the explicit specialization
template <> class X<1>;
// Then define the default behaviors of X.


// X.cpp
#include "X.h"
template <>
class X<1>{
public:
    X() = default;
    X(int& a) {--a;}
    // define X<1>
};
// Then specialize behavior.


// main.cpp
#include "X.h"

int main(){
    X<2> x_2; // fine, instantiates the default version
    X<1> x_1(); // Edit: A function declaration, as pointed out in the comment.
    X<1> x_1_1; // error: aggregate ‘X<1> x_1_1’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    int a = 0;
    X<1> x_1_2(a); // error: variable ‘X<1> x_1_2’ has initializer but incomplete type
}
```

Comment: `X<1> x_1()` is simply a function declaration

Comment: The empty parentheses create a function, it does not call the default constructor or create an object.

Comment: @0x499602d2,. Got it, thanks. But what about the other two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by others `X<1> x_1();` is only a function declaration, so it doesn't actually instantiate an object of type `X<1>`. For the `incomplete type` error: You have to put the whole *declaration* of `X<1>` into the header file (not only a forward declaration, as you did now). You can put the *implementation* in the cpp file, but anyone using objects (and not only pointers to objects) of type `X<1>` (in this case: `main`) has to know how large it is and what methods it provides.

Your confusion might in part stem from the way you use specialisation in your example: In your specialisation, the only thing that differs from the general template is the definition of one of the constructors (all the signatures stay the same). So you might have thought the compiler could figure this out by itself. In fact, it cannot possibly do that, because your specialised class might look completely different (with different constructors, different members/member functions) from the unspecialised template. Like this:

```
template <int I>
struct X {
    bool hello(int x, int y);
};

template<>
struct X<1> {
    int goodbye(std::string x);
};
```

If the compiler only sees `template<> struct X<1>;` instead, how should it figure out the interface of this class?

Comment: Got it. I thought including the definition of the specialization would cause multiple definition errors, and that's why I've put the definition of the specialized in a cpp. Thank you.

Comment: Just look at it like a regular non-template class: The whole declaration (with signatures of member functions, member variables, etc.) has to go into the header to "announce" the structure of the class to its users. What the methods actually do can go into the cpp file, because its irrelevant for the interface. When you say "definition", technically, you are therefore only referring to the *declaration* of the specialised template (not the definition of the methods).

Answer (score 4):

`template <> class X<1>;` is just a forward declaration of the specialization, and conveys no information about the layout of the type.  Since the actual specialization is not visible from `main.cpp` (it is defined in `X.cpp`), the type is indeed incomplete.

Keep in mind that class template specializations share nothing with the template class other than its base name, so the compiler has *no idea* how many bytes to allocate on the stack for each instance (nor whether the requested constructor even exists!) unless it knows the definition of the specialization, which you have hidden away in a .cpp file.

This is akin to doing `class Foo;` and then trying to declare a variable of type `Foo` without providing a definition of the type.

Comment: Indeed. It doesn't know how to construct the object, or whether it even has a constructor with that signature. With function templates it's different, since you have enough information to figure out what the specialization symbol would be called.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. Previously I had a function template and I have to put the (fully, as requested by the standard) specialized version in a cpp with forward declaration. (I read that this is in general a bad idea--specializing function templates--after I did it.) That led me to doing the same thing here. Thank you both @YamMarcovic.